# Restore overwritten files and directories in Dropbox

Tags: file, directory, dropbox, restore

Does anyone know how to restore previous versions of files/directories that have been accidentally overwritten (copied over) in Dropbox? I'm happy to restore the entire directories from the previous day. I'm pretty desperate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox does offer an API you can use for listing and restoring versions of files, among other operations. You can find everything you need to get started with the Dropbox API, including documentation, tutorials, and SDKs here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers

Specifically, to list files, use:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder
- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue

And to list the different versions of a file, you would use:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_revisions

And to restore a file to a particular version:

- https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-restore

Those are links to the documentation for the HTTPS endpoints themselves, but we recommend using one of the official SDKs if possible:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation

Those have corresponding native methods for the HTTPS endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Greg, All is good! Dropbox restored the files for me as they hold 30 days worth of backups.